# How can a "Connection reset" error be prevented when closing a client socket?

Tags: java, sockets, stream

Forgive me if this is simple, as I'm fairly new to server/client coding and am trying to teach myself.

I've made a server and client which work fine and interact perfectly while both are running.  The problems I run in to are when I exit the application that contains the client.  As soon as I do, I get an unending error saying:

```
null -- Connection reset
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:113)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:107)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:93)
java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:151)
```

Calling the `close()` method on the client's reference to the socket doesn't seem to have any effect on this whatsoever.  I tried calling `if(socket.isClosed())` from the server, but it says it's still open even after the client has closed it.

How can I handle closing streams and sockets gracefully when my application exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, you can send some command that will tell your server application to close the connection.

Comment: Yep pretty much this, have your middleware pass an `end of stream message` of some kind as a shutdown hook in the client. so the server knows to stop reading from the socket. of course for durability you should be able to handle an unexpected `IOException` anyway.

Comment: @lynks: exactly. This should be considered more like a hint to the server, not the ultimate means to shut down the channel.

Comment: Gotcha.  I guess I figured that since both the client and the server had a reference to the socket connection that they should be able to tell independently when the other one "hung up" on the line.  This helped me though, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly you are reading past EOS and possibly still sending data in the server. Contrary to Alexander Pavlov's answer, you don't need to send a special message, as you already get an EOS indication when reading, but you do need to take note of the EOS indication that is sent by the client close.